# javascript error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am getting this error when I call a javascript function to display a modal window:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

The code block is:

```
else if (action=="officeview") {
    document.getElementById("OfficeContent").src="ChangeView.aspx";
    ShowFeatureModal('AppView','OfficeContent')
```

The object is this situation, does exist.

Error is caused at: `document.getElementById` line.
What else could be causing the error?

**Update:**
Index.aspx is calling the javascript function which is located in sysUtilities.js file.  The source file is yet a seperate page (ChangeView.aspx)

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns `null` if the element is not found, and accessing `.src` of `null` is not allowed. Where are you using this code?

Comment: If you look at the source code of your page (in the browser), can you find a HTML element with `id="OfficeContent"` ?

Comment: @DigitalPlane not sure what you mean by "where am I using this code" It is being used client side, to call a modal window. The user clicks a hyperlink, and this code block is called.

Comment: @M4N... the page ChangeView.aspx does not load.... when I click on the hyperlink, nothing happens (except for the javascript crash dialog box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `document.getElementById` doesn't find the element, it will return `null`. If you then try to get the `src` property from `null`, you'll get this error.

You'll either need to ensure the there's an element with its ID equal to `OfficeContent` or do something like the following:

```
else if (action=="officeview") {
    var officeContent = document.getElementById("OfficeContent")
    if (officeContent) {
        officeContent.src="ChangeView.aspx";
        ShowFeatureModal('AppView','OfficeContent')
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you're using ASP.NET, which it appears that you are, remember that your IDs might be getting name-mangled if they are inside a container control. In that case, you have to make sure to use the `ClientID`, not the plain old `ID`. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("<%= OfficeContent.ClientID %>")
```

Comment: ok, so according to your code, my application does not get to officecontent.src=""ChangeView.aspx";     the only issue is that a div called OfficeConent does exist in ChangeView.aspx

Comment: With this error, that is the likeliest possibility. `OfficeConent` is different from the id in your code, which is `OfficeContent`. Maybe this is typo?

Comment: nope... that was my typo on this board; no typo in actual code;

Comment: If you run it through a script debugger, what do you see?

Comment: it just says "object required"

Comment: Again, it's pointing to the fact that you don't have an element with the ID "OfficeContent". See my edit for another possible fix.

Comment: The puzzling thing is that this is an exact copy and paste code from other modal popup windows, which work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will help in this case, but this is a trick to prevent the error:

`(document.getElementById("OfficeContent")||{}).src="ChangeView.aspx";`

If the element doesn't exist, an empty object gets the `src`-property, no error is thrown, no harm is done.

It may be wise though to look for the cause of `document.getElementById("OfficeContent")` returning null.

Answer (score 0):

you need test whether an element exists first before setting element's src attribute

```
var el = document.getElementById("OfficeContent");
el && (el.src="ChangeView.aspx");
```

Comment: That results in an error, as you are trying to assign to an invalid lvalue.

Comment: If OfficeContent doesn't exist,document.getElementById("OfficeContent") will return null.

Comment: Yes, but you can't assign to `el && el.src;` in `el && el.src="ChangeView.aspx";`. That results in an error - try it in a console.

Comment: This is not valid.  Running this code would result in `Reference Error: Invalid left-hand assignment.`

Comment: el && (el.src = "ChangeView.aspx") is correct,sry miss typing

Comment: it's just a tricky to avoid writing `if (condition) { action }`

Answer (score 0):

All this stuff is peripheral to the main issue, which is:

You must use the actual clientID of "OfficeContent", which may be quite different in the HTML DOM of the page as it is rendered. One easy way to avoid this would look something like this:

var officeContent = document.getElementById("<%=OfficeContent.ClientID %>")